# iOS In-App Purchases - Download or unlock new content?

Tags: iphone, ios, storekit, in-app-purchase

In my game, I'm planning to add IAPs for different level packs that the player will be able to buy and play in the game. But after reading documentations on IAPs, there's still one question I'm wondering : **Is it better to download the new content from Apple's server, or unlock it in the game with NSUserDefaults?**

The problem is that if I chose option 2, the content will be easily hackable, and the app will need an update for each DLC I'm adding.

And the problem with option 1 is that the new content will be downloaded in the Documents folder, but my app search the list of levels in the resource folders (I know it's not hard to implement, but I'm just saying the pros and cons)

**Anyone can tell me which one is the best practice, and why?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think both options are good. Whats the size of these packs? If you have numerous iaps all consisting of new levels, id recommend to have them downloadable, imagine shipping the app without the extra levels, quite a network-loadoff.

As you are stating, option nr 1 gives you the ability to add levels dynamically. This is convenient since apple are quite slow when it comes to uploading of new builds. Come to think of it, they are not super fast when it comes to revising your DLC either.

Due to the hacking risk and initial reduction of app-filesize, I would definately go with option one but if possible, i'd provide the actual content from a private FTP server. That way, the new content is available directly.

Comment: Do you have any link to share on how to build a private FTP server for IAPs? I have yet to learn server programming...